# Dynamic variables in looper

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, while-loop, looper

This is my simple looper code

```
foreach( $cloud as $item ) {

    if ($item['tagname'] == 'nicetag') {
        echo $item['tagname'];
            foreach( $cloud as $item ) {
                echo $item['desc'].'-'.$item['date'];
            }
    } else 
        //...
    }
```

I need to use `if` method in this looper to get tags with same names but diferent descriptions and dates. The problem is that I dont know every tag name becouse any user is allowed to create this tags.
Im not really php developer so I'm sory if it's to dummies question and thanks for any answers!

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about what you want to do?

Comment: Hello Paul. I need to find all [tagname] values in multidimensional array and if value is duplicate, loop there [desc] and [date] values. In output it must be somethink like this:

- first tag
-- nice description 12 - 02-02-2014
-- nice description 52 - 05-02-2014
-- nice description 13 - 07-02-2014
- second tag
-- nice description 11 - 03-02-2014
-- nice description 51 - 04-02-2014

Maybe I need to rebuild an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to declare a temporary variable that will hold *tagname* that is currently looped through:

```
$currentTagName = '';
foreach( $cloud as $item ) {
    if ($item['tagname'] != $currentTagName) {
        echo $item['tagname'];
        $currentTagName = $item['tagname'];
    }

    echo $item['desc'] . '-' . $item['date'];
}
```

I presume that your array structure is as follows:

```
$cloud array(
    array('tagname' => 'tag', 'desc' => 'the_desc', 'date' => 'the_date'),
    array('tagname' => 'tag', 'desc' => 'the_desc_2', 'date' => 'the_date_2'),
    ...
);
```

**BUT**

This solution raises a problem - if your array is not sorted by a tagname, you might get duplicate tagnames.

So the better solution would be to redefine your array structure like this:

```
$cloud array(
    'tagname' => array (
        array('desc' => 'the_desc', 'date' => 'the_date'),
        array('desc' => 'the_desc_2', 'date' => 'the_date_2')
    ),
    'another_tagname' => array (
        array('desc' => 'the_desc_3', 'date' => 'the_date_3'),
        ...
    )
);
```

and then you can get the data like this:

```
foreach ($cloud as $tagname => $items) {
    echo $tagname;

    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo $item['desc'] . '-' . $item['date'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This is it :)
May I ask you how to redefine this array? It will be really great

Comment: You need to rewrite the function/method where this array is built, because restructuring the current array is not very efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that I get array using WP_Query. I dont really belive that I can to rewrite this function by myself... so maybe I just sort array by a tagname...

Comment: Maybe you can try altering the query itself (the parameters sent to WP_Query) to get the array you need? Or at least add an _order by_ clause so you don't need to sort the array manually. I don't have much experience with WordPress though...